# How to Escape Property References in an OSGi Blueprint Properties file?

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to create a property in an OSGi properties file, where the property is a simple string, such as

```
fileName=${header.RecordType}.csv
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, and I assume that is because the `${...}` is being processed as a property reference by the configuration manager, and since it doesn't exist as a property, is being blanked.

I've tried escaping the simple string reference as `$${` and `\${` but neither work.

Is it possible to somehow escape the `${` so that the property passed to the program is exactly as shown above?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fileName=$simple{xxxx}` as alternative syntax, which is also documented here:
https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/simple-language.html

Comment: Thanks! I've read that page so many times and never noticed that line. D'oh!